# JSoup 404 Error on a working website

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse HTML of a website. It was working fine till yesterday. But now i have started receiving this error:

> HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404,
>   URL=http://www.dawn.com/pakistan/punjab

The site is working perfectly fine on Browser. But not using Java. The code i used is below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(srcLink)
                .userAgent("Mozilla")
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .timeout(20000)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .get();
```

I also tried this, but failed again :

```
String srcLink = source;
URL url = new URL (srcLink);
URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlCon.getInputStream());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8", srcLink);
```

Please help me . I will be thankful .

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you might be behind a proxy. try setting the proxy properties and invoke your code

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "1.2.3.4");// Your proxy
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234"); // Your proxy port

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(srcLink)
    .userAgent("Mozilla")
    .maxBodySize(0)
    .timeout(20000)
    .followRedirects(true)
            .get();
```

Comment: No. It is not the issue either ! all the other links are working fine . even other links of the same website too. but not the ones inside the "pakistan" tab. i.e. http://www.dawn.com/pakistan/****

Comment: What are trying to retrieve from this website? It works fine. I tried `Jsoup.connect("http://www.dawn.com/pakistan/").get();`